# About 404 during WordPress installation

Tags: php, wordpress

I am learning wordpress, I think I have installed it according to the installation instructions, but the result is `404`

1. Download wordpress (ok)
2. Create a database for WordPress on your web server, and also create a MySQL user with all permissions to enter and modify. (ok?)
3. Rename the wp-config-sample.php file to wp-config.php.(ok)
4. Open wp-config.php with your favorite text editor and fill in your database information.(ok?)
5. Put the WordPress folder on your server where you want to put it(ok?)
6. Visit wp-admin/install.php in your favorite browser to launch the installer(404)

Why?

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using web server to run wordpress site (ex:xampp, wamp v...). Are you change directory of variable DocumentRoot and Directory in httpd.conf point to wordpress directory?

Comment: oh~no，Wordpress is outside the specified folder  ，clear~，arigatou

Comment: You are getting error 404 when go to install.php of wordpress, maybe web server don;t point to wordpress directory. Please try create a file test.html in wordpress folder and go to this file with URL "http://yourdomain.com/test.html". Is it run success?